# Show status of Rails test in status bar of Vim?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim

Is there any known Vim plugin that would show if a Rails test is passing or failing by showing a green or red bar respectively. I personally find Growl notifications quite distracting and am looking for an alternative but can't find anything. [Something similar to this is what I'm aiming for.](http://vimeo.com/8569257).

**EDIT: I'm using MacVim on OSX 10.6**

Comment: Is that Gary's screencast? I actually wrote the routine that he uses to show the colored bars. I'll post it as an answer as soon as I get back to my computer.

Comment: Yes, it's Gary Bernhardt's awesome string calculator kata in Python video. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Autotest::Screen`?

I'm not a ruby person, but the trick was not so complicated.
All you need to do is to detect file changes under the specific project directory, run your test then bring test result back to Screen's status bar.

Comment: I am using MacVim on OSX 10.6. I should have mentioned this earlier, my mistake. Thus, cannot use Screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have in my `$VIMFILES/ftplugin/python/tests.vim` file:

```
function! RunAllTests(args)
    silent ! echo -e "\033[1;36mRunning all unit tests\033[0m"
    if filereadable(getcwd() . "/runtests.py")
        set makeprg=./runtests.py\ --with-machineout
    elseif filereadable(getcwd() . "/manage.py") && filereadable(getcwd() . "/settings.py")
        set makeprg=./manage.py\ test\ --with-machineout\ --verbosity=0
    else
        set makeprg=nosetests\ --with-machineout
    endif
    exec "make! " . a:args
endfunction

function! JumpToError()
    if getqflist() != []
        for error in getqflist()
            if error['valid']
                break
            endif
        endfor
        let error_message = substitute(error['text'], '^ *', '', 'g')
        silent cc!
        if error['bufnr'] != 0
            exec ":sbuffer " . error['bufnr']
        endif
        call RedBar()
        echo error_message
    else
        call GreenBar()
        echo "All tests passed"
    endif
endfunction

function! RedBar()
    hi RedBar ctermfg=white ctermbg=red guibg=red
    echohl RedBar
    echon repeat(" ",&columns - 1)
    echohl None
endfunction

function! GreenBar()
    hi GreenBar ctermfg=white ctermbg=green guibg=green
    echohl GreenBar
    echon repeat(" ",&columns - 1)
    echohl None
endfunction

let maplocalleader=","
nmap <LocalLeader>a :call RunAllTests("--machine-out")<cr>:redraw<cr>:call JumpToError()<cr>
nmap <LocalLeader>A :call RunAllTests("")<cr>
```

I originally based it off Gary's .vimrc, and then moved some things around and recoded the method that shows the bars.

I'm sure it can be easily adapted to ruby and whatever it uses for test running (I'm not a ruby guy). This currently uses [nosetests](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) for running python tests.

Hope that helps!